# Asynchronous client / server c# problem with second communication

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, server, thread-safety

I´m struggling with problem that after first success full connection with sockets I can establish second without errors. What to do ? I have give there both application so you can try help me troubleshoot that problem. Thanks you very much guys!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

namespace AsynchronousClientLearning
{
    class Program
    {
        public class ObjectState
        {
            public const int BufferSize = 256;
            public Socket wSocket { get; set; } = null;

            public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        }

        public class AsyncSocketClient
        {
            private const int Port = 4343;
            private static ManualResetEvent connectComplete = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            private static ManualResetEvent sendCompleted = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            private static ManualResetEvent receiveCompleted = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            private static string  response = String.Empty;

            public static void StartClient()
            {

                try
                {
                    IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                    IPAddress ip = ipHost.AddressList[0];
                    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, Port);

                    Socket client = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    client.BeginConnect(remoteEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ConnectionCallback) , client);
                    Send(client, "this socket message<EOF>");
                    sendCompleted.WaitOne();

                    Receive(client);
                    receiveCompleted.WaitOne();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Response received {response}");
                    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    client.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

            }

            private static void Receive(Socket client)
            {

                try
                {
                    ObjectState state = new ObjectState();
                    state.wSocket = client;
                    client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer,0,ObjectState.BufferSize,0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }

            private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    ObjectState state = (ObjectState)ar.AsyncState;
                    var client = state.wSocket;
                    int byteRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
                    if(byteRead > 0)
                    {
                        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, byteRead));
                        client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, ObjectState.BufferSize, 0,
                            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(state.sb.Length > 1)
                        {
                            response = state.sb.ToString();

                        }
                        receiveCompleted.Set();

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }

            private static void Send(Socket client, string data)
            {
                byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), client);

            }

            private static void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                    int byteSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                    Console.WriteLine($"send: {byteSent} bytes to server");
                    sendCompleted.Set();
                    client.DisconnectAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }

            private static void ConnectionCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                client.EndConnect(ar);
                Console.Write($"Socket connection : {client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()}");

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to contine");

            Console.ReadLine();

            AsyncSocketClient.StartClient();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server console application**
that should be taking care about cca 10 clients so thread for everyone is not solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

namespace AsynchronousServerLearning
{
    class Program
    { public class ObjectState
        {
            public Socket wSocket = null;
            public const int bufferSize = 1024;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
        public class AsyncSocketListener
        {
            public static ManualResetEvent allCompleted = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            public static void StartListener()
            {

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                IPAddress ip = ipHost.AddressList[0];
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, 4343);
                Socket listener = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                try
                {
                    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                    listener.Listen(100);
                    while(true)
                    {

                        allCompleted.Reset();
                        Console.WriteLine("waiting for incoming connections......");
                        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
                        allCompleted.WaitOne();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }

            private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                allCompleted.Set();
                Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

                ObjectState state = new ObjectState();
                state.wSocket = handler;
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, ObjectState.bufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }

            private static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                string content = String.Empty;
                ObjectState state = (ObjectState)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = state.wSocket;
                int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
                if(bytesRead > 0)
                {

                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                    content = state.sb.ToString();
                    if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>", StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Read: {content.Length} bytes from \n socket Data: {content}");
                        Send(handler,content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, ObjectState.bufferSize, 0,
                            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

                    }

                }
            }

            private static void Send(Socket handler, string content)
            {
                byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
                handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
            }

            private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                    int byteSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sent {byteSent} to client");

                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();

                }
                catch( Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
            AsyncSocketListener.StartListener();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Log from console:

```xml
Press any key to continue

Socket connection : [fe80::3d32:e16b:6438:ad43%8]:4343send: 24 bytes to server
Response received this socket message<EOF>

send: 24 bytes to server
Response received this socket message<EOF>
Socket connection : [fe80::3d32:e16b:6438:ad43%8]:4343System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult, SocketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at AsynchronousClientLearning.Program.AsyncSocketClient.ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar) in C:\Users\Z660659\source\repos\AsynchronousClientLearning\AsynchronousClientLearning\Program.cs:line 82
```

...when I try that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to contine");

    Console.ReadLine();

    AsyncSocketClient.StartClient();
    Console.ReadLine();
    AsyncSocketClient.StartClient();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: *"...about cca 10 clients..."* What does "cca" means?

Comment: It wanted more text to add. So I just said that my intention is to create C<->S app that will be used by 10 clients

Comment: Why are you disconnecting the socket in AsyncSocketClient.SendCallback before you receive the server's reply? This will cause your receive function to fail.

Comment: What you mean send please example I think i ran into that issue. When two clients are trying speak at once.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for answear like 2 hours since I struggle. Now I came with solution that solver the error. With reseting manualReserEvents. If you found something better please let me know.

```
 private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                ObjectState state = (ObjectState)ar.AsyncState;
                var client = state.wSocket;
                int byteRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
                if(byteRead > 0)
                {
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, byteRead));
                    client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, ObjectState.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(state.sb.Length > 1)
                    {
                        response = state.sb.ToString();

                    }
                    receiveCompleted.Set();
                    connectComplete.Reset();
                    receiveCompleted.Reset();
                    sendCompleted.Reset();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```